# Как через код изменить прозрачность кнопки?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно сделать так, что когда игрок входит в определенную область, кнопка изменяет свою прозрачность, но у меня никак не получается, что я только не пробовал, какой код только не вставлял, не понимаю свою проблему

Вот один из примеров, как я пробовал это реализовать, но не работает

```
public Button KillButton;
```

```
    if (collision.tag.Equals("KillRadius"))
        {
            KillButton = GetComponent<Button>();               
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                transform.position = enemy.transform.position;
                var KillButton = gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
                var colors = KillButton.colors;
                colors.normalColor = new Color(255, 255, 255, 250);
                KillButton.colors = colors;

            }
        }
```

Comment: 1) На чем у вас висит скрипт. 2) if находится внутри какой функции?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Скрипт висит на игроке, это OnTrigger, тоесть когда игрок входит в определенную зону, то кнопка должна менять свою прозрачность
Внутри функции OnTriggerStay2D

Comment: Так вы делаете: `KillButton = GetComponent<Button>()`, то есть вы берете компонент кнопки висящий на игроке, а не на кнопке? Если этот код не выдает ошибку, а судя по тому, что вы про это не написали он ее не выдает, значит вы хотите сказать, что у вас на игроке висит компонент Button

Comment: @МаксимФисман в этом и проблема, я не знаю, как обратиться к кнопке, идей нету и я уже все облазил
Это делается через Find("Tag")?

Comment: Ответ дам в ответаъ

Comment: Кстати, функця GameObject.Find(string s) находит объект НЕ по тегу, а по НАЗВАНИЮ, вы почему то написали Find("Tag").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из комментариев понял, что вы не знаете как обратиться к кнопке.
Первый вариант: создать публичную переменную типа GamaObject, в которую в инспекторе перетащим нашу кнопку:

```
publiс GameObject myButton;
```

Назвать можем естественно как хотим переменную.
Теперь получаем из нее компонент button следующим образом

```
Button buttonComponent = myButton.GetComponent<Button>();
```

Однако это очень муторно и бесполезно: лишняя переменная, лишняя строчка кода, к тому же в нашей кнопке обычно ничего, кроме самого компонента Button нам не нужно, поэтому лучше создадим переменную СРАЗУ типа данных Button:

```
public Button myButton;
```

Причем в инспекторе ничего не меняется: просто также перетягиваем кнопку.

Теперь в переменной хранится КОМПОНЕНТ BUTTON ВАШЕЙ КНОПКИ.
Цвет можем поменять следующим образом:

```
Color color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 250);
myButton.colors.normalColor = color;
```

**Не нужно создавать лишние переменные такие как var killButton**, вы напрямую пишите
`кнопка.цвета.нормальныйЦвет = мойЦвет`

Можно естественно не оборачивать color в переменную и указать напрямую, как сделали вы:

```
myButton.colors.normalColor = color;
```

> Если мой ответ вам помог, примите его, поставив галочку, если у вас остались вопросы - задавайте их в комментариях:)

> Не нужно это делать в методе OnTriggerStay, потому что он вызывается каждый кадр, когда есть контакт. Вызывайте в OnTriggerEnter

> Попробую угадать, вы случайно не Among Us делаете?

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, но у меня вылазит ошибка, подчеркивает Kill.colors и пишет, что не удалось изменить возвращаемое значение, тк как оно не является Переменной
```public Button Kill;

if (collision.tag.Equals("KillRadius"))
        {               
            Color color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 250);
            Kill.colors.normalColor = color;
        }```

Comment: Я сейчас открою свой тестовый проект и попробую, но перед этим хотел бы вам напомнить, что я отвечал на ваш вопрос "Почему при спавне объект отображается, но не показывается". Мой овтет вы так и не приняли. Вы смогли решить тот вопрос?

Comment: [здесь](https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/thread2373496.html). Пишите:` GetComponent<Graphic>().color` вместо `GetComponent<Button>().colors.normalColor`. Другой вариант: менять сразу цвет в компоненте Image, который тоже висит на кнопке `GetComponent<Image>().color`

Comment: @MAXEMGAAA ну что? Ответите на последние 2 сообщения?